# AutoMapper - Mapping objects in a class library to objects in a silverlight class library

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, automapper

I am trying to use automapper to map a list of objects in a class library to a list of objects in a silverlight class library. I am getting a security exception as AutoMapper is trying to reflect over the silverlight class library.

Does anyone know of a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm literally working on a SL 3.0 port *right now*.  It should be released in about a week or so.  If you can't wait, check out this branch folks have been using in the meantime: http://github.com/detroitpro/AutoMapper.Silverlight

Comment: Great thank, if i wanted to do the mapping in an asp.net application, how do you deal with having to reference both system.dll 2.0.0.0 and system.dll 2.0.5.0?

Comment: I'm releasing two assemblies, an AutoMapper.dll and AutoMapper.Silverlight.dll.  I had to do conditional compilation etc. to basically leave out things that SL does not support (system.data for example).

Comment: Hey Jimmy, is the Automapper Silverlight port dead in SL 4.0?

Comment: Right now I'm just planning to release a SL4 port once 2.0 is out.